# SQL: Inconsistent column values after self-join

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm using BigQuery to compute pairwise distances of vectors.  Each row has a vector of weights.

Here's the query.  The first parts just generate random data.  The important part is the final `SELECT` statement in which I compare each document to every other document via a self-join.

```sql
WITH input_data AS (
  SELECT
    document_id
  FROM UNNEST(["doc1", "doc2"]) AS document_id
),
exploded AS (
  SELECT
    document_id,
    STRUCT(dimension_id, rand() AS weight) AS weight
  FROM
    input_data CROSS JOIN UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1, 3)) AS dimension_id
),
rows_with_weights AS (
  SELECT 
    document_id,
    ARRAY_AGG(weight) as vector
  FROM 
    exploded 
  GROUP BY 
    document_id
),
SELECT 
  l.document_id as l_doc_id,
  r.document_id as r_doc_id,
  l.vector as l_vectors,
  r.vector as r_vectors
FROM 
  rows_with_weights AS l 
CROSS JOIN rows_with_weights AS r WHERE l.document_id <= r.document_id
```

You'll see that I also compare each document to itself, and here's where something unexpected happens: when a document is compared to itself, the values of `l_vector` are distinct from those of `r_vector`.  Here's the output of the above query:

[image]

This is puzzling.  I would expect these two vectors to be the same for the same document.  What's going on here?

Comment: Why is there a `rand() as weight` there. If I was debugging this myself that would be my first suspect.

Comment: I just wanted to create random values for my toy dataset.  I agree that if I used constant values there rather than calling random(), this problem likely wouldn't exist.  However given my understanding of SQL the results here are surprising and need an explanation.

Comment: It almost seems like the query optimizer has modified the execution plan to first perform the self-join, and then create the random numbers.  This doesn't seem like a valid thing to do though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What's going on here?

This is as expected!

BigQuery does not materialize the results of CTEs. If CTE is referenced in multiple places in a query, then the CTE is executed once for each reference. Which means that when you do self join you actually join two tables with different weights. Thus the result

I recommend to use temp tables instead so randomness will be materialized once and then you will get expected result

Comment: Woah!  Thank you for the clarification.  This is surprising, and a blow to my basic intuition that I can just query CTEs as if they were tables.  This means we have a self-join with a table and its 'evil twin', rather than a self-join between a table and its identical self.  Is this sort of thing standard in SQL systems?  Is this well documented somewhere?